# Error en PHP relacionado con JSON

Tags: php, json

Estoy montando una pagina actualmente para un bot de discord que estoy desarrollando, por ahora no esta pensado en incluir un diseño css, pero necesito buscar una forma para arreglar el error que esta relacionado con json (para cargar la configuración de la pagina)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="es">
<title> Turret Bot Main Page </title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $configuracion = file("config.json");
        $jsonified = json_decode($configuracion);
        $maintenance = $jsonified->{'maintenance'};
        echo $maintenance;
        sleep(1);
        if ( $maintenance == true){
            echo "<h1> Error </h1>";
            echo "<p>This server is in maintenance</p>";
        } 
    ?>
</body>
```

ese es la configuracion de la pagina, la pagina home.php tambien lleva un sistema de comprobacion de mantenimiento, que deberia de redireccionar a esta automaticamente si la opcion esta activa

el json: (sencillo por ahora, pero ira avanzando

```
{
    "maintenance": true
}
```

De hecho, este es el error

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/vol14_2/epizy.com/epiz_25647923/turretbot.epizy.com/htdocs/index.php on line 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La advertencia *`json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`* se debe a que estás usando `file()`, la cual devuelve un array, como bien ha indicado @Ibai A. en su respuesta.

No obstante, convendría que consideres controlar posibles errores en tu código y simplificar la sintaxis.

Veamos una versión más simple y clara de tu código, que controla posibles errores:

```
/*
    Dado que ambas funciones devuelven false en caso de error
    puedes hacer un control de ambas de este modo
*/

if ( $jsonified = json_decode(file_get_contents('config.json')) ) {
    /*
        Dado que json_decode (sin parámetro true)
        devuelve un objeto JSON, puedes usar la sintaxis
        $objeto->clave para obtener los datos, de modo que esto
        $jsonified->{'maintenance'} no tiene mucho sentido
        Por otra parte, los valores booleanos pueden compararse directamente
        en un if sin usar operadores de comparación,
        pues sería como hacer esto if (true == true) 
        en vez de hacer simplemente if (true) ...
    */

        sleep(1);
        if ( $jsonified->maintenance ){
            echo "<h1> Error </h1>";
            echo "<p>This server is in maintenance</p>";
        } 
} //Aquí eventual control en caso de fallar el json
```

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

La función `file()` genera un array con el archivo que le mandas, como puedes ver aquí en la documentación de [file](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file.php)

Para abrir un archivo json, de la manera que tu estás buscando puedes usar la función [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$configuracion = file_get_contents('config.json');
```

De esa manera el json decode ya no deberia darte el error que te da ya que ahora `$configuracion` si que debería de ser un string.

Answer (score 0):

Estas llamando config.json pero no invocas que llave o raíz necesitas: $configuracion["?"]; Prueba hacerle un var_dump() a $configuracion para ver como esta compuesta.

Comment: Esto parece más bien un comentario en lugar de una respuesta. Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges) podrás dejar comentarios en las preguntas. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Utilice file_get_contents() en lugar de file(), y debe fluir la ejecución sin detenerse

```php
$configuracion = file_get_contents("config.json");
```